# Population overlap of random distributions of binary choices

Tags: probability, binary-data, finite-population, choice-modeling, overlapping-data

I’m trying to figure out how to calculate the overlap (concurrence) of certain building features, for example: high-efficiency windows, thick insulation, efficient lights, etc. I know the probability of the individual features (e.g. 20% of buildings use efficient lights, 30% have thick insulation) but would like to know the likely segment of the building population when 1, 2, 3, up to n different features overlap. That is, when they do overlap, how big is that overlap likely to be? I know it can’t be bigger than the least likely feature, but can I say anything more about the size of the overlap? Each feature is independent of whether another feature exists in the building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "overlap" is what most statisticians call concordance or agreement. In particular, a measure called [Cohen's Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa). The Cohen's Kappa is attractive because it accounts for the unconditional frequency of each trait. For instance, if 20% of buildings use energy efficient lights, and 30% have "thick" insulation, right off the bat we expect 6% of homes to have both if there's no association between them. However, the Kappa can be as high as 95.7%. If all 20% of the energy efficient light buildings also had thick insulation, then the "agreement" is 90%, and the Kappa is calculated as 0.9/(1-0.06) = 0.957

To my knowledge, there is no established multivariate analogue of Cohen's Kappa, such as in your case where you're considering more than one feature. However, you can certainly create a matrix of pairwise Kappas between each trait. The same type of display is usually done with Pearson correlation when considering multiple continuous measures and their associations.

Comment: Many thanks! I think this is an appropriate way to look at this. One question is how was the 90% agreement calculated?

Comment: @Determinant scroll down to the "Hypothesis testing and confidence interval" of the wiki for details of the SE calculation.